# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes in django while running python manage.py migrate after inspectdb

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-mysql

I connected my Django with mysql database and ran a sql script to make a database and ran migrations on my django project and I had no errors but to to use the database I had to use python manage.py inspectdb >appname/models.py ,
after doing this I cleaned my models as it was mentioned in the steps but when I ran
python manage.py migrate it gave me this error:

MYSQL script

```
create database if not exists payroll_db;
use payroll_db;
create table m_state(state_code varchar(2) primary key, state_name varchar(30));

create table m_address(address_id integer primary key,building_details varchar(30) NOT NULL, road varchar(20) NOT NULL,landmark varchar(30) NOT NULL, city varchar(30) NOT NULL,state varchar(2) NOT NULL references m_state(state_code),country varchar(30) default 'India');

create table m_company(company_id integer primary key, company_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, building_details varchar(30) NOT NULL, Area Varchar(30),  Landmark Varchar(30), City varchar(30), state varchar(2) NOT NULL references m_state(state_code),country varchar(30) default 'India');

create table m_department(company_id integer NOT NULL references m_company(company_id),department_id integer primary key,department_name varchar(30) NOT NULL);

create table m_grade(grade_id integer primary key, grade_name varchar(20) NOT NULL);

create table m_employee(employee_id integer primary key,employee_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,department_id integer references m_department(department_id),company_id integer NOT NULL references m_company(company_id), building_details varchar(30) NOT NULL, Area Varchar(30),  Landmark Varchar(30), City varchar(30), state varchar(2) NOT NULL references m_state(state_code),country varchar(30) default 'India',  employee_doj date NOT NULL, grade_id integer NOT NULL references m_grade (grade_id));

create table m_paygrade(employee_id integer NOT NULL references m_employee(employee_id) ,grade_id integer NOT NULL references m_grade(grade_id),basic_amt integer NOT NULL,da_amt integer NOT NULL,pf_amt integer NOT NULL,medical_amt integer NOT NULL,primary key(employee_id,grade_id));

create table m_pay(employee_id integer NOT NULL references m_employee(employee_id),fin_year integer NOT NULL, gross_salary integer NOT NULL,gross_dedn integer NOT NULL,net_salary integer NOT NULL, primary key(fin_year, employee_id));

create table t_leave( employee_id integer NOT NULL references m_employee(employee_id) ,fin_year integer NOT NULL,leave_date date NOT NULL, leave_type varchar(4) check (leave_type IN('CL','SL','PL','LWP')));

create table t_achievement(employee_id integer NOT NULL references m_employee(employee_id),achievement_date date NOT NULL, achievement_type varchar(80) NOT NULL);
```

**django models.py code:**

```
from django.db import models
# class AuthGroup(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'auth_group'


# class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
#     group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
#     permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
#         unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


# class AuthPermission(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
#     content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
#     codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'auth_permission'
#         unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


# class AuthUser(models.Model):
#     password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
#     last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
#     is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
#     username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
#     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
#     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
#     email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
#     is_staff = models.IntegerField()
#     is_active = models.IntegerField()
#     date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'auth_user'


# class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
#     user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
#     group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
#         unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


# class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
#     user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
#     permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
#         unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


# class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
#     action_time = models.DateTimeField()
#     object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
#     object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#     action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
#     change_message = models.TextField()
#     content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
#     user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'django_admin_log'


# class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
#     app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#     model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'django_content_type'
#         unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


# class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
#     app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
#     applied = models.DateTimeField()

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'django_migrations'


# class DjangoSession(models.Model):
#     session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
#     session_data = models.TextField()
#     expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

#     class Meta:
#         managed = True
#         db_table = 'django_session'

class MState(models.Model):
    state_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_state'


class MAddress(models.Model):
    address_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    building_details = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    road = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.ForeignKey('Mstate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_address'


class MCompany(models.Model):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_details = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    area = models.CharField(db_column='Area', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    landmark = models.CharField(db_column='Landmark', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.CharField(db_column='City', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    state = models.ForeignKey('Mstate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_company'


class MDepartment(models.Model):
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('MCompany',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_department'


class MGrade(models.Model):
    grade_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    grade_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_grade'


class MEmployee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    department_id = models.ForeignKey('MDepartment',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('MCompany',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    building_details = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    area = models.CharField(db_column='Area', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    landmark = models.CharField(db_column='Landmark', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.CharField(db_column='City', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    state = models.ForeignKey('Mstate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    employee_doj = models.DateField()
    grade_id = models.ForeignKey('MGrade',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_employee'

class MPaygrade(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey('MEmployee',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade_id = models.ForeignKey('MGrade',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    basic_amt = models.IntegerField()
    da_amt = models.IntegerField()
    pf_amt = models.IntegerField()
    medical_amt = models.IntegerField()
    paygrade_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_paygrade'
        unique_together = (('employee_id', 'grade_id'),)


class MPay(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey('MEmployee',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fin_year = models.IntegerField()
    gross_salary = models.IntegerField()
    gross_dedn = models.IntegerField()
    net_salary = models.IntegerField()
    MPay_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'm_pay'
        unique_together = (('fin_year', 'employee_id'),)

class TLeave(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey('MEmployee',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fin_year = models.IntegerField()
    leave_date = models.DateField()
    leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    leave_id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 't_leave'


class TAchievement(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey('MEmployee',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    achievement_date = models.DateField()
    achievement_type = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    achievement_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 't_achievement'
```

**error traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error, the output file has null bytes \0x00 that u need to inspect and remove manually with python.

u may try something like this

```
content = []
with open('crm/models.py', 'r') as file_in:
    content = file_in.readlines()

new_content = [] 
for line in content:
    clean_line = line.replace('\00', '')
    new_content.append(clean_line)

with open('models2.py', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in new_content:
        file_out.write(line)
```

or print every line and copy and paste also worked